Order of nester requestAnimation frame seems incorrect
What I want to achieve is 2 loops (anim1 and anim2), while anim2 contains nested loop internalAnim2
The output of the following code should be:
anim1 - 4 times (= a1Max)
and 5 times (=a2Max) those 3 lines:
anim2
anim2 - internal anim
anim2 - internal anim
const a1Max = 4;
var anim1counter = a1Max;
const a2Max = 5;
var anim2counter = a2Max;
const ia2Max = 2;
var internalAnim2counter = ia2Max;
var animationFrameID = null;
var internalAnimFrameID = null;

function anim1() {
    console.log("anim1");
    if (anim1counter > 0) {
            animationFrameID = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                anim1();
                
            });
        anim1counter--;
    } else {
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameID);
        anim1counter = a1Max;
        anim2();
    }
}

function anim2() {
    console.log("anim2");
    internalAnim2();
    if (anim2counter > 0) {
            animationFrameID = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                anim2();                
            });
        
        anim2counter--;
    } else {
        anim2counter = a2Max;
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameID);
        
        anim1();
    }
}

function internalAnim2() {
    console.log("anim2 - internal anim");
    if (internalAnim2counter > 0) {
            internalAnimFrameID = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                internalAnim2();
            });
        internalAnim2counter--;
    } else {
        internalAnim2counter = ia2Max;
        cancelAnimationFrame(internalAnimFrameID);
    }
}

anim1();
      

The presented code snippet seems to make sense, but the output is:
anim1
anim2
anim2 - internal anim
anim1
anim2 - internal anim

anim2 is not waiting for internalAnim2(); to finish

@Bergi what's the solution? I've added await in line 27 - the whole execution got paused forever

There are no promises here so await won't help. The point is that if (anim2counter > 0) { runs immediately after you started internalAnim2(). You need to pass a callback, or start the actual content of anim2 in the else part of internalAnim2 - just like you called anim2() from anim1 only when it has finished doing its thing.

Why do you want to have multiple parallel loops if you want them to be synchronized? They'll anyway fire at the same frequency (monitor's refresh rate) so there is nothing to win by splitting them in their own callbacks. The easiest is to have a single "master" loop, which then does coordinate your various calls the way you want, synchronously.

@Kaiido You are right - I don't want pararell loops

@Bergi I am not sure how to use this callback

@niepodam Add a parameter for the callback to internalAnim2. Forward it to the recursive call. Call it (with no arguments) when done.
